# Initialize read only array only once

Tags: c++

I have a class that needs to use some big arrays, initialized via some complex functions, that will be the same for every instance and will only be read after initialization.

I searched on SO and found some answers on initializing static arrays like this:

```
char A::a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

But in my case I need to calculate the arrays at runtime via some function.
(How) can I do it?

Comment: You could simply use a static pointer and allocate space for it at runtime with new/delete..

Comment: many ways to do it.  1 - have an init function that you call first thing on main, 2 - pre-calculate and do what you're doing now, 3 - use std::vector, and have an initialize function that returns a vector: std::vector<char> A::a = createInitialA();, 4 - in the constructor of A, check if a is initialized.  if not, initialize it by calling an init function as in (1).

Comment: @tux3 Why are you recommending dangerous tools like `new` and `delete` to a beginner?

Comment: @райтфолд because the OP is already working with raw arrays, so I assumed it was intentional. But I agree that a vector would probably be a good idea.

Comment: I think #3 from my previous comment is the cleanest way to do something like this.

Comment: @tux3 Right, they're already doing it wrong (C-style arrays instead of `std::array`), so let's teach them more wrong things? Great logic.

Comment: Maybe we could try to stay adult and professional, hmm? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re

> **”** will be the same for every instance and will only be read after initialization

Producing a value is the job of a function.

Just define a function that returns the data you need.

You can use it to initialize a static data member (or whatever). For a header only module, if that's relevant, you will need to employ solution to the "inline data" problem, e.g. a Meyers' singleton (a function that returns a reference to a local static variable). Like this:

```
#include <vector>

namespace my {
    using std::vector;

    inline
    auto squares()
        -> vector<int>
    {
        vector<int> result;
        for( int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i ) { result.push_back( i*i ); }
        return result;
    }

    class A
    {
    private:
        static
        auto a()
            -> const vector<int>&
        {
            static const vector<int> the_values = squares();
            return the_values;
        }

    public:
        A(){}
    };
}  // namespace my
```

Comment: Why inside the class `A`?  I've seen most of this before, but not as a class member.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Just because the OP apparently's aiming for something like that,  mentioning a "class that needs" and with example `char A::a[6]`.

Comment: I think I understand, but just to be sure: squares is called only the first time an A instance calls A::a? And is the code simplified if I don't need an header only module?

Comment: what happens if this goes into the .h file?

Comment: @mfran: yes, and yes (it's *possible* to simplify it, e.g. using a static const data member).

Comment: @thang: This code is designed as a header only module. It's possible to put it in an implementation file instead, but then the `inline` doesn't serve any purpose and can/should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use {} sintaxis in execution time, you can use a method:

```
class A
{
   static vector<char> a;
   //...
   public:
   static void initStatic();
}

void A::initStatic()
{
    a.resize( /*put the size here... */);
    for (auto& x : a)
        x = //something...
}
```

vector reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @райтфолд why did you put other reference? Oo

Comment: Because cplusplus.com is well-known for being wrong, incomplete and misleading.

Comment: @райтфолд: It was, several years ago. It's much better now.

Comment: cppreference is worst, i think *_*.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using vectors, this works.  The reason I let `A::initialize` do the work, rather than just calling one of these externally defined functions, is that we can and should expect the data member `a` to be private.

```
//Declare a function pointer type, so you can pass it into A's
//an initialization function takes in the array and its size
typedef void (*initFunction) (char A[], int arraySize); 
//see http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html
//  for more on function pointers

class A
{
public:
  void initialize (initFunction myInitFunction);
  ...
private:
  char a[ARRAYSIZE];
};

void A::initialize (initFunction myInitFunction)
{
   (*myInitFunction) (a, ARRAYSIZE);  
}

...
A myA;
myA.initialize (yourArrayInitializingFunction);
```

Or maybe your initialization functions don't take in arrays and initialize them, but return arrays:

```
class A
{
public:
  void initialize (const char* aInit);
  ...
};

void A::initialize (const char* aInit)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE: ++i)
     a[i] = aInit[i];
}

...

A myA;
myA.initialize (yourArrayReturningFunction ());
```

If you're using vectors, code is simpler:

```
class A
{
public:
  void initialize (const vector<char>& aInit) { a = aInit; }
  ...
private:
  vector<char> a;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion:

1. Instead of using a static member variable, use a static member function to provide access to the array.
2. In the static member function, create a static function variable that can be populated the first time it is needed.

Here's what I am thinking of:

```
char* A::getArray()
{
   static char a[6] = {0};
   static bool inited = false;
   if ( !inited )
   {
      // Initialize the array elements 
      a[0] = ...  ;

      ...

      a[5] = ...  ;

      inited = true;
   }

   return a;
}
```

Comment: This is truly terrible code. Not only do you use terrifically unsafe native arrays and obscenely confusing array-to-pointer-decay, but it's just got to be a mutable global too...

Comment: @Puppy: What in particular is "unsafe" or "confusing" here? (Hint: nothing; you're cargoing. Or PMSing. Can't quite tell which.)